# How to install package before executing command in puppet?

Tags: dependencies, puppet

In a puppet class, I have something like this:

```
package {'python2-pip':
    ensure => installed,
} ->
exec {'pip install nltk':
    command => 'pip install nltk',
    creates => '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk',
}
```

The expected result is to first install pip, then install nltk. Unfortunately, I get the error message:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Validation of Exec[pip install nltk] failed:
'pip install nltk' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify
the command or specify a path.
```

It seems Exec is trying to evaluate the command before Package has installed the package. Why is this happening, and how can I make the dependencies execute in the right order?

Comment: The error message explains it: you need to specify the path to the pip executable.

Comment: Oh and actually you should use the `package` resource with the `pip` provider instead. That would be much better and fix your problem.

Comment: Ummm... @MattSchuchard, the point of the code snippet above is that the `Package` resource is installing `pip`. There is no path to the pip executable, until after the `Package` resource installs it, but since puppet is throwing an error, puppet doesn't install the package. I was able to solve this specific issue by using `package {'nltk': ensure => installed, provider => pip, }` But the question still stands in general. Somebody might, for example, instead of installing pip and then using pip, install zip and then use zip, or something like that.

Comment: Glad you used my comment to solve your problem. Both my mentioned solutions of fixing the error message and using the `package` resource are short and simple though, so I do not feel they qualify as answers (although the former has been used an answer by another already below). To be honest, both solutions of using an `exec` instead of a `package` with a provider and fixing the bad path error have been asked and answered before already on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343387/matt-schuchard) comment above, go to the server in question and run `which pip` to see pip's location (on my machine `/usr/local/pip`), then append your exec command with the full path for pip, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/pip install nltk`

Puppet doesn't have all the pathing/env variables you're used to as a regular user, so you need to be verbose when specifying commands.